# How to fix rewrite url workers

Tags: javascript, cloudflare

In the last month, I have used the below code to do direct, but "*Error 1101 Worker
threw exception*" has been coming out for 2 days, I can't understand what has changed.

I have tested other code, but same problem.

```js
addEventListener("fetch", event => {
    let requestURI = new URL(event.request.url);

    if (requestURI.hostname == "mynametitle.workers.dev") {
      event.respondWith(rewriteURL(event.request));
    }
})

async function rewriteURL(request) {
    var URI = new URL(request.url);

    URI.protocol = "http";

    {
        URI.hostname = "urldestinationexample";
        return fetch(URI, request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are 2 possible causes for the above error.

- 1. You are forced migrate from Service Worker to ES Module.
- 2. The error is caused by the worker code, most likely coming from the upstream query (fetch).

Should. Test the upstream query at your computer (development environment), ensuring the query to the target address is valid. Also wrap the `fetch(...)` code inside an error catcher, try to handle the exception and return the appropriate response so you can immediately see the specific cause.

If. All solutions with the current codebase do not solve the problem, try migrate the codebase to ES Module.

[Migrate from Service Workers to ES Modules](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/reference/migrate-to-module-workers/)